# Ring + Vibrate not available in 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920, ringtone, vibration

I am using a Nokia Lumia 920. Previously in Windows Phone 8.0 I was able to on my vibration while ringing. But when I upgraded it to 8.1, it no longer have option of vibrate + ring.

I number of times getting into trouble because of this, in crowd, or while traveling I do not understand my phone is ringing or not.

If it's default feature of 8.1 can you suggest any app which can override this feature?

Answer (score 7):

You can toggle vibrate on and off in the volume bar:

[image]

Press either of the volume keys to open the volume bar, then expand it by tapping the chevron. Tap the "VIBRATE ON"/"VIBRATE OFF" icon to toggle vibrate.

Alternatively, go to Settings → ringtones+sounds, you can also toggle vibrate there.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a default feature of windows 8.1
You can get the vibration on/off option on the volume bar which appears when you press either of the two.. or you can also go to settings-> ringtones+sounds->vibrate- on/off.

[image]